# Importing WSL2 from my old laptop keeps reinstalling Ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, wsl2

I am attempting to configure a new laptop (Windows 10 Enterprise Version 20H2). I have installed WSL with the `wsl --install` command recommended by Microsoft.

I have managed to import a backup of my previous WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 configuration and have set that as the default distribution.

```
PS C:\Windows\System32> wsl --list --verbose
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-20.04    Stopped         2
```

However, when I attempt to launch Ubuntu (wanting my old config) from the launcher in the start menu, it installs a fresh version of Ubuntu and launches that

```
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
Please create a default UNIX user account. The username does not need to match your Windows username.
For more information visit: https://aka.ms/wslusers
Enter new UNIX username:
```

I've tried removing the unwanted instance with

```
PS C:\Windows\System32> wsl --unregister Ubuntu
```

But the problem persists. So how can I get the launcher (or whatever the correct term is in Windows) to launch the default version?

Comment: `wsl --unregister Ubuntu` should be `wsl --unregister Ubuntu-20.04`.  The easier solution is import the instance you exported using a different other than `Ubuntu`.  Based on the list of instances you have, it does not appear, you have imported anything

Comment: No. Ubuntu20.04 is the image I had backed up on my old laptop. Ubuntu is the one which is installed against my wishes.

Comment: I suggest you try my suggestion then reimport your instance, because whatever you are launching, is NOT the instance you think it.  Ubuntu on the Windows Store is the "current" version while `Ubuntu-20.04` on the store is a specific version.  You should reimport your instance as something other than `Ubuntu` or `Ubuntu-20.04` and then update your list showing that particular instnace you reimported is NOT running.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound, but it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WSL only creates Start menu "launchers" (shortcuts) for distributions that you install via either:

- `wsl --install -d <distro>`
- `wsl --install` (the default Ubuntu distro with WSL)
- Or those installed from the Microsoft Store

Those Start menu items point to what is called an "app execution alias", and you can see these in the "Manage App Execution Aliases" in Settings.

At the moment, you have two instances competing with each other:

- `Ubuntu`:  Installed via the `wsl --install` process and what appears on the Start menu.
- `Ubuntu-20.04`:  Your `wsl --import`ed instance.  There is no Start menu item for this.  Typically you would launch it via either:

  - The `wsl` command
  - A Windows Terminal profile (which would actually launch `wsl -d Ubuntu-20.04`

You have multiple options to do what you want:

- Option 1 (recommended):  Install Windows Terminal from the Microsoft Store.  This is the (relatively) new terminal that is:

  - Much more feature-rich than, and designed to replace Windows Console Host (which is used by WSL, PowerShell, CMD, and other terminal applications by default)
  - Developed by Microsoft
  - Open-source ([github repo](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal)
  - Currently very actively developed, with regular new feature releases
  - Able to become the default terminal in Windows 11
  - Able to automatically detect and create profiles for all WSL instances you have installed.

  Instead of launching "Ubuntu" from the Start menu, just launch Windows Terminal instead.  Since it will automatically create a profile for Ubuntu_20.04, you can even set this profile to be the default.  Launching Windows Terminal will then automatically start your Ubuntu_20.04 instance.
- Option 2 (the next-best option if you don't want to use Windows Terminal): Create a Start menu item for Ubuntu-20.04:

  - If you want to get rid of the Start menu item for the "Ubuntu" distribution, right click on it in the Start menu and "Uninstall".  This will get rid of the `ubuntu.exe` (the app execution alias) and the Start menu item.
  - To create a new Start menu item pointing to the default distribution:

    - Navigate in Explorer to `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu`
    - Right-click and select *New* -> *Shortcut*
    - For the "Location", just enter `wsl.exe` (even `wsl` will do)
    - Name it "Ubuntu"
- Option 3: `wsl --import` your preferred distribution and give it the name `Ubuntu`.

  - `wsl --unregister Ubuntu` (the one installed via `wsl --install)
  - `wsl --import Ubuntu <directory> <your_20.04.tar> --version 2`
  - When you launch Ubuntu from the Start menu, it should launch your distribution now, since it is looking for the one named `Ubuntu`, not `Ubuntu-20.04`.
- Option 4: For WSL2 installations, you can copy your `ext4.vhdx` file from the imported instance over that of the existing Ubuntu instance.  This isn't necessarily recommended for this use case, as the previous method is safer and works just as well.

  - Start "Ubuntu" from the Start menu and configure it with a dummy user.
  - `wsl --shutdown` to make sure no instances are running.
  - Copy the `ext4.vhdx`:

    - *From*: the location where you `wsl --import`ed
    - *To*:  The stock Ubuntu installation.  You should find this in something like `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited...\LocalState`.
  - Start "Ubuntu" from the Start menu, and it should have your Ubuntu-20.04 installation.
  - Change your default distribution to this one via `wsl --set-default Ubuntu`
  - Once you are satisfied everything is working properly, `wsl --unregister Ubuntu-20.04`.  Remember, **this is a destructive operation**, so make sure you have everything working and confirm that you are using the `Ubuntu` distribution first.  Better yet, `wsl --export` it one more time and back it up before doing so.